# undefined reference to `SetTextColor@8'

Tags: g++, compilation, mingw, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I got the "undefined reference to `SetTextColor@8' " error while compiling a c++ program using g++ under windows. The complete error log is here http://pastebin.com/DCwHKkeE
I guess i am missing some library file but don't know which ones. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SetTextColor` func is defined in gdi32.lib according to the MSDN docs, so you'll need to link `libgdi32.a` in mingw.

Answer (score 0):

Just link the libgdi32 and it should be fixed.

```html
g++ -g main.cpp -o main.exe -lgdi32 -lmingw32
```

Comment: You might like to read [Can I answer questions on Stack Overflow and promote my website link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349792/can-i-answer-questions-on-stack-overflow-and-promote-my-website-link)